# Laplacian under conformal diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $(M^n,g)$ and $(N^n,h)$ are two Riemannian manifolds with metric $g,h$. Assume there is a conformal diffeomorphism  $F$ between them, say $F:M\rightarrow N$. It means that $\mu g=F^*h$ for positive function $\mu$ on $M$. Now consider a smooth function $u\in C^\infty(N)$, I am wondering if following two quantities are the same:
$$\Delta_h u=\Delta_{\mu g}u\ \circ F$$

Can we check it by using local coordinates or local O.N. basis ?

What I tried after hint by  Ted Shifrin, I did the calculation in one dimension, $M$ is one manifold with coordinate $t$, and $N$ is one manifold with coordiante $s$ and with metric $h=l(s)ds^2$, the metric $F^*h=l(F(t))F'(t)^2 dt^2$, then by $$\Delta_h u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{l}}\partial_s(\sqrt{l}\frac{1}{\sqrt{l}}\partial_s u(s))$$
and
$$\Delta_{F^*h} u(F(t))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{l(F(t))F'(t)^2}}\partial_s(\sqrt{l(F(t))F'(t)^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{l(F(t))F'(t)^2}}\partial_s u(F(t)))$$
At point $s=F(t)$, they are same. I realize it may just be a problem about the coordinate change. Higher dimensional case is probably the same.

Comment: Have you tried working out what happens in dimension 1 or 2?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Under_a_conformal_change

Comment: @TedShifrin, thanks, I think they are same.

Comment: @WillieWong, Thanks for the response, I am not asking how Laplacian changes under conformal metric here. But the next step is pull out the factor $\mu$ by conformal formula you mentioned.

Comment: If there is a diffeomorphism $F$, then you can identify $(N^n,h)$ as $(M^n, \mu g)$ and you can use the conformal change formula directly.